# Product of projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

> > If $P_{1}=\frac{\alpha_{1}\beta_{1}^{T}}{\alpha_{1}^{T}\beta_{1}}$ and $P_{2}=\frac{\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}^{T}}{\alpha_{2}^{T}\beta_{2}}$, then
> >
> > $P_{1}P_{2}=\frac{\alpha_{1}\beta_{1}^{T}}{\alpha_{1}^{T}\beta_{1}}\frac{\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}^{T}}{\alpha_{2}^{T}\beta_{2}}$, where $P_{i},\;i=1,\;2$ are rank-1 projectione matrices.

However, if the situation like this

> > $\frac{\alpha_{2}^{T}\beta_{1}}{\alpha_{1}^{T}\beta_{1}}\frac{\alpha_{1}\beta_{2}^{T}}{\alpha_{2}^{T}\beta_{2}}$, then how to express the latter in terms of projection matrices?

Comment: Are you asking that how to express the latter in terms of the product of two projection matrices given the definition of $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: @UnbelieveTable, Yes

Comment: Is your first fraction really what it looks like? A fraction of two numbers?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, yes the first fraction is a number.

Answer (score 1):

Your two products are the same (assuming that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2$ are column vectors of the same size): that is,
\begin{align}
\frac{\alpha_{2}^{T}\beta_{1}}{\alpha_{1}^{T}\beta_{1}}\frac{\alpha_{1}\beta_{2}^{T}}{\alpha_{2}^{T}\beta_{2}}
= \frac{\alpha_{1}\beta_{1}^{T}}{\alpha_{1}^{T}\beta_{1}}\frac{\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}^{T}}{\alpha_{2}^{T}\beta_{2}} .
\label{darij1.eq.1}
\tag{1}
\end{align}

*Proof.* Forget about the denominators; they are just scalars and they are the same on both sides. Thus, it remains to prove that $\left(\alpha_2^T \beta_1\right) \left( \alpha_1 \beta_2^T\right) = \left(\alpha_1 \beta_1^T\right) \left(\alpha_2 \beta_2^T\right)$.

Now, let $\lambda$ be the scalar $\alpha_2^T \beta_1$; thus, to be fully precise, $\alpha_2^T \beta_1 = \lambda I_1$. Hence, $\lambda I_1 = \alpha_2^T \beta_1 = \beta_1^T \alpha_2$ (since $x^T y = y^T x$ for any two column vectors $x$ and $y$). Now,
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\left(\alpha_2^T \beta_1\right)}_{=\lambda} \left( \alpha_1 \beta_2^T\right) &= \lambda \left(\alpha_1 \beta_2^T\right)  = \alpha_1 \underbrace{\lambda I_1}_{= \beta_1^T \alpha_2} \beta_2^T = \alpha_1 \left(\beta_1^T \alpha_2\right) \beta_2^T = \left(\alpha_1 \beta_1^T\right) \left(\alpha_2 \beta_2^T\right) .
\end{align}
And this is precisely what we needed to prove.